# How to display the date on the x-axis in highstock?

Tags: javascript, api, highcharts

I need to display date/time on the x-axis. Now on the x-axis some strange data  00 00 00 001, 00 00 00 002. I want to see 1.08.2014 22.01.01 (day.month.year hour.minute.second).
My JSON data:

```
[
    ["30 June 2014 19:14",24],
    ["30 June 2014 19:16",41],
    ["30 June 2014 19:16",12],
    ["30 June 2014 19:16",8]
]
```

Etc. (time,value).

My Javascript code - it work but not to display date/time on the x-axis:

```
var seriesOptions = [],
seriesCounter = 0,


//My data
names = ['data_input_1', 'data_input_2'],colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
//My graph captions
captions = ['Датчик 1', 'Датчик 2'];
//Type of my two graph - 2 lines
type = ['line', 'line'];

//Configure graph (now 2 names so 2 graph)
$.each(names, function(i, name) 
{
//get data
$.getJSON('../graph/select_data.php?'+ name.toLowerCase() +'',  

function(data) 
{
seriesOptions[i] = 
{
name: captions[i],
data: data,
type:type[i],
//I think- this is the place for code, that i want
// it doesnot work here categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
// all other code here - work well

};

seriesCounter++;
if (seriesCounter == names.length){createChart();}
});
});
```

Result:

[image: Result]

How to display the date on the x-axis in highstock for my two lines?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your JSON data. It is not in a format that Highstock can immediately utilize to show as `datetime` on the x-axis. The problem is that your strings, for example "30 June 2014 19:14", are not [timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

The x-axis needs timestamps in milliseconds (since 1. January 1970). Beware that some timestamps received from other sources may be in seconds, not milliseconds. If that is the problem you must multiply them by 1000.

When using strings it won't really make sense to Highstock, so Highstock just pretends the timestamp of your data is 0, 1, 2... which translates to 00:00:00.000 (0 milliseconds), 00:00:00.001 (1 millisecond), 00:00:00.002 (2 milliseconds)...

You need to convert your string representation of a date into a timestamp. I'm not sure if you can manipulate the format you receieve your JSON in, but if you can't you can post-process it to transform the data, like this ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b25DY/2/)):

```
var data = [
    ["30 June 2014 19:15",24],
    ["30 June 2014 19:16",41],
    ["30 June 2014 19:17",12],
    ["30 June 2014 19:18",8]
];

var timestampData = [];

for(i in data) {
    timestampData.push([new Date(data[i][0]).getTime(), data[i][3]]);
}


$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    series: [{
        data: timestampData
    }]
});
```

The essence here is that `new Date(data[i][0])` parses your string into a Date-object with values for year, month day... And you then use the `getTime()` function of that object to get the timestamp.

Comment: Ondkloss, i understand that data must be in timestamp.
I try this variant too. But it does not work as i want.




My JSON data:[[1406772865,24],[1406772976,41],[1406772977,12],[1406772978,8],[1406830911,47],[1406838142,35],[1406843275,24]]
My javascript code in first post.




Result
http://i051.radikal.ru/1408/78/5adc0bec9191.jpg
Convert 1406772976 - result Thu, 31 Jul 2014 02:16:16 GMT
Highstock show Sun, 17 Jan, 06:46:12.976
Highstock display wrong date on the x-axis an in the hint.
What wrong?

Comment: I apologize. I see that my answer may be confusing in that regard. Your JSON data uses seconds since 1. January 1970. Highcharts uses **millseconds** since 1. January 1970. If you add three zeros behind every timestamp it is all fine.

Comment: I may add that the `getTime`-function also uses timestamps in milliseconds, which is why that approach works.

Comment: Ondkloss, i do it, but it does not correctly work.
My json now is [["1406772865000",24],["1406772976000",41],["1406772977000",12],["1406772978000",8],["1406830911000",47],["1406838142000",35],["1406843275000",24]]
Result
http://s55.radikal.ru/i149/1408/30/e946e6a098c1.jpg
What should I change in my javascript code in place "//I think- this is the place for code, that i want" ?

Comment: But now you are back to strings again. It can't be quoted. Just plain numbers, that are timestamps in milliseconds. http://jsfiddle.net/b25DY/6/

Comment: I back to strings again and now use milliseconds without the quotes.
My data now [[1.406772865e+12,24],[2.813545841e+12,41],[4.220318818e+12,12],[5.627091796e+12,8],[7.033922707e+12,47],[8.440760849e+12,35],[9.847604124e+12,24]].
It strange, but php output numbers in this format.
I use php code $date=((int)$row[date]*1000);
Dates have become almost as I want. But something strange on the x-axis again. 
Highstock inserts an extra value (date). There's no point but has a date.
I have 7 points, but 9 dates. May be my json data incorrect again?
http://i024.radikal.ru/1408/d5/eb770ae04300.jpg

Comment: There is nothing to indicate to me that you should be getting that result from the given data. You will have to produce a JSFiddle example to show it. Also, it seems more like labels than points? In any case, this is getting slightly off topic from the timestamp/date problems that were initially occuring.

Comment: You need to have this figure of json [1406772865,24],[1406772976,41],[1406772977,12],[1406772978,8],[1406830911‌​,47],[1406838142,35],[1406843275,24]] but each timestamp should be multiplied by 1000